# AS3 - Multiple addEventListener(KeyboardEvent) - Same Key but different Action

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events, addeventlistener

i hope, my English is good enough, that you understand my Explanation and my "Problem"!

**Endgoal**

To navigate through a Presentation with a single Key, but a different action ...

1. Switch between Movieclips
2. gotoAndPlay inside a Movieclip

**Status**

I just started to build a Presentation with an AnimateCC Presentation Template,

which look like this ...

**Maintimeline**

AS3 Actions for Navigation
and a Movieclip called "slides_mc"

```
// EVENTS
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_changeSlide);

function fl_changeSlide(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == 37) // LEFT
    {
        fl_prevSlide();
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) // RIGHT
    {
        fl_nextSlide();
    }
}
// END EVENTS



// FUNCTIONS AND LOGIC
function fl_prevSlide():void
{
    if(slides_mc.currentFrame > 1)
    {
        slides_mc.gotoAndStop(slides_mc.currentFrame-1);
    }
}
function fl_nextSlide():void
{
    if(slides_mc.currentFrame < slides_mc.totalFrames)
    {
        slides_mc.gotoAndStop(slides_mc.currentFrame+1);

    }
}

slides_mc.gotoAndStop(1);

// END FUNCTIONS AND LOGIC

stop();
```

**Movieclip slides_mc**

Inside slides_mc, i have multiple Movieclips (01, 02, 03,...) on the Timeline filled with Content.

A few Movieclips are splitted inside with stop-Commands, 
where i like to navigate with the *same* Keypress!

**Build Overview**

```
Maintimeline
-> Actions
-> Movieclip (slides_mc)

slides_mc
-> multiple Movieclips (01, 02, 03)

Movieclips (inside)
-> Singlestop on the Endframe ... stop();   //on Keypress (next Slide)  or
-> Multiplestops ... stop(),.... stop(),.... stop();  //on the same Keypress (next Frame)
```

**Problem**

Jumping between the Movieclips works like it should, 
but i don't know, what to do, 
that inside a Movieclip,
another Action get called, with the *same* Keypress, like this

```
stop();


addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveForward);

function moveForward(event:KeyboardEvent):void

{
    if(event.keyCode == 39)

    {
        gotoAndPlay (nextFrame);
    }
}
```

I thought, its simple to implement, but the more i read, 
the more questions i got ;(

**IMPORTANT!**

It has to be, the SAME Key, because i use a Handpresenter with only two Buttons (Forward, Backward)!

**Solutions i think off**

1. "Overrule" the stage.EventListener on specific Frames
2. Exception on the Maintimeline/Actions (if necessary for each movieclip)
3. remove / add EventListener  (stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_changeSlide); ... always failed, not finding a connection for fl_changeSlide)

So, is there any "simple" ;) Way, to get this working, or is it easier, just to split the Movieclip in more Movieclips and be happy with the Script i already have!?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT / Progress 1**

thanks for trying to help ... yes, sounds simple, 
but since i'm no Coder, it's just Trial & Error for me.

For now, i tried adding into my Mainscript:

```
stage.addEventListener("FirstOfFrames", CallBackFirst);

function CallBackFirst (event:Event):void

{
    trace("First");
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_changeSlide);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveForward);
}



stage.addEventListener("LastOfFrames", CallBackLast);

function CallBackLast (event:Event):void

{
    trace("Last");
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveForward);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_changeSlide);
}
```

and inside my Movieclips on the First Frame:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("FirstOfFrames"));
```

and on the Last Frame:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("LastOfFrames"));
```

I'm on the right way? ;)

**EDIT / Start from cratch 1**

Thank you sooo much BadFeelingAboutThis, that's much more help (& code needed :)) than i expected! No way to get this, just with Trial & Error!

But looks like, i do something wrong - now it's acting like i have a stop(); in every single frame.

**Started with a Testfile from scratch** 
*What i have done:*

1. *Create two .as Files* (Slide.as and NavigationEvent.as) 
   and copy & paste your Code in it
2. Create a new *.fla in the same folder
3. on the *Maintimeline*, i copy & paste your *Keyboard Definitions* under Actions
   and create a Movieclip called slides_mc
4. inside the MC slides_mc, i create a few other MCs (01, 02, 03) filled with a few frames, but without any code (no stop();)
5. in one MC, i set a few stops over some frames ...
   for this MC i set

   stage.dispatchEvent(new NavigationEvent(true)); 
   //pass false for back, true (or nothing) for forwards

in the Maintimeline

6. At last, i edit my SymbolProperties (for slide_mc and the MCs 01, 02, 03), check "Export for ActionScript", define a Classname for every Single MC and enter Slide into Base Class (Confirmed ok through the Testoption)
7. Try to run it (without any given Errors) in the Test Environment of Animate itself, 
   export direct as *.swf and export as (Win & Mac)Projector, 
   always with the same Result -> in every MC (with or without content), 
   every Keypress just move 1 Frame (forward & backward)

Are there any Tips, you can give me, what i may have forgot or done wrong?

PS: Since this post getting longer and longer, is it better to delete the "Beginning of the Post", or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're on the right path with point 3.

You have two handlers for the same event that perform conflicting actions. So you have to turn on off while the other is active.
You cannot remove the eventListener from inside the clips, because you have no reference to the handler function, so you have to do it on the main timeline.

on the main timeline remove the listener once it triggers and moves slides_mc to the next slide. then register the listener to control the current slide. once you're at the end of that slide, remove it's listener and notify back (custom event) to the main timeline that you're done so it can re-register the main one and navigate to the next slide ... simple enough right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one (of many) ways you can accomplish what you'd like.

### Use a custom class (or two), to minimize code redundancy.

In the same folder as your .fla, create a new text file, and call it `Slide.as`. Paste the following code into it and save.  (please look at the code comments for some explanation as to what the code is doing).

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Slide extends MovieClip
    {
        //static vars belong to the class as a whole, not an individual instance of a class.
        //this static var is used to determine if the most recent navigation event was forwards or backwards
        public static var forwards:Boolean = true;

        public var myPriority:int; //the priority this slide has to control navigation

        //this functions runs when the instance of this class is first created
        public function Slide() 
        {           
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage, false, 0, true);
            this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStage, false, 0, true);

            stop(); //let's stop by default, so you don't have to do it for each and every clip;

            //if moving backwards, go to the last frame
            if (!forwards) {
                this.gotoAndStop(this.totalFrames);
            }
        }

        //this function will run when the instnace of this class is added to a timeline
        private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
            //find the first Slide parent (if any) and listen at 1 higher priority than it
            var p:DisplayObjectContainer = parent;
            while (p && p != stage) {
                if (p is Slide) {
                    myPriority = Slide(p).myPriority + 1;
                    break;
                }

                p = p.parent;
            }

            //listen for the navigate event, incriment priority everytime a slide is loaded so the most recently loaded slide is always in control
            stage.addEventListener("Navigate", navigateHandler, false, myPriority);

        }

        private function removedFromStage(e:Event):void {
            //remove the listener when this movie clip is unloaded from the screen
            stage.removeEventListener("Navigate", navigateHandler, false);
        }

        private function navigateHandler(e:NavigationEvent):void {
            //If the navigation is forward, and this movie clip isn't on the last frame
            if (e.isForward && this.currentFrame != this.totalFrames) {
                forwards = true;
                this.nextFrame();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //cancel the event from reaching the others listening for it
            }

            //If the navigation is backwards, and this movie clip isn't on the first frame
            if (!e.isForward && this.currentFrame != 1) {
                forwards = false;
                this.prevFrame();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //cancel the event from reaching the others listening for it
            }

            //if we didn't stop the propagation of the event, the next lowest priority listener will execute
        }

    }

}
```

Again, create a new file and call this one `NavigationEvent.as`.  Paste this code and save:

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class NavigationEvent extends Event 
    {
        public var isForward:Boolean = true;

        public function NavigationEvent(isForward_:Boolean = true) 
        {
            isForward = isForward_;
            super("Navigate", true, true);      
        }
    }
}
```

### Attach the custom class to each slide asset

Next, in your flash pro library, right click each slide MovieClip (including slides_mc) and open it's properties, and check the '*export for actionscript*' checkbox. 
Give it a unique class name, and then in the base class, put `Slide`.

[image: Make your slides inherit all the code from the custom class]

This will have the slide asset inherit all that code you pasted in the custom class file.

### Create Navigation Events From User Input

Next, in your main timeline, you'll want to create a navigation event anytime you want the navigation to change (eg keyboard or button click).

```
stage.dispatchEvent(new NavigationEvent(false)); //pass false for back, true (or nothing) for forwards
```

Here is a full example using the standard PowerPoint keyboard shortcuts (Most PowerPoint remotes use PageUp/Down as the keyboard event)

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);

function keydown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch(e.keyCode){
        //FORWARD KEYS
        case Keyboard.SPACE:
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        case Keyboard.PAGE_DOWN:
            stage.dispatchEvent(new NavigationEvent());
            break;

        //PREVIOUS SLIDE KEYS
        case Keyboard.BACKSPACE:
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        case Keyboard.UP:
        case Keyboard.PAGE_UP:
            stage.dispatchEvent(new NavigationEvent(false));
            break;
    }
}
```